# Consider two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ with well-defined means such that $X ≤ Y$, show that $E[X] ≤ E[Y]$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ with well-defined means such that $X ≤ Y$, show that $E[X] ≤ E[Y]$.

We were given a hint that we should write $p_X (x) = p_Y (x) + d^+(x) − d^−(x)$ where
$d^+(x) := max\{p_X (x) − p_Y (x), 0\}$ and $d^−(x) := | min\{p_X (x) − p_Y (x), 0\}|$

but this just made me more confused because I thought it was pretty easy just to say that since $X$ and $Y$ had well-defined means, then $X$ would have mean $μ_x$ and $Y$ would have mean $μ_y$ and since $E[X] = μ_x$ and $E[Y] = μ_y$ then $E[X] ≤ E[Y]$.

Clearly, I am wrong. Any insight as to why the hint was given and how it would be used to show that $E[X] ≤ E[Y]$?

Comment: The hint you were given is nonsense. The decomposition $u=u^+-u^-$ (with $u^+=\max(u,0)$ and $u^-=|\min(u,0)|$) must not be applied to $u=p_X(x)-p_Y(x)$ but to $u=x$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use the definition of the Lebesgue integral and prove by hand that for $f,g \in L^1(\mu)$ with $f \leq g$  $\mu$-almost everywhere we have
$$\tag{$\ast$}\int f \, \mathrm{d} \mu \leq \int g \, \mathrm{d} \mu.$$
That is a fundamental property of most integrals. (If you already proved this statement in your course, then, in fact, the hint would make no sense.)

Prove first that $X^+ \leq Y^+$ and $Y^- \leq X^-$ and that ($\ast$) holds for positive functions. Next deduce (by using the decomposition $X= X^+ - X^-$, $Y = Y^+ - Y^-$ that $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y]$.